# Casper JS: TypeError: 'null' is not an object

Tags: javascript, null, phantomjs, typeerror, casperjs

I am trying to grab the "David Welsh" text on this page: http://foster.uw.edu/faculty-research/directory/david-welsh/

When I do `document.getElementById('Boundless').children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML` in the browser console, I successfully select the text I want, but when I run my js file in Terminal, I get the error:

`TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('Boundless').children')`

Why is this working in my browser but not in my local js file?

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.each(links,function(self,link){
        self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
            var name = document.getElementById('Boundless').children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML;
                casper.echo(name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd start by examining the state of the document inside of your thenOpen() callback; sounds like it's not what you're expecting.

Comment: The document is correct. I have it printing out the URL before it tries grabbing this text, and its on the URL I want it to be on.

Comment: It may have the right URL, but have failed to load the document in the state you expect for a variety of reasons...including the page in the browser having gone through post-load DOM manipulation via JS that isn't being run when you open it in casper.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Do you know how I should go about checking the state or what I should do next?

Comment: Personally, I'd toss a breakpoint in there, run it in debug, and examine the contents of the document object directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS which has two contexts. The page context ([`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)) is sandboxed. It is the only way to access the DOM, you need to use it.

```
var name = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return document.getElementById('Boundless').children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML;
});
casper.echo(name);
```

Everything that you want to use inside of it, you have to explicitly pass in. It has no access to variables defined outside.

The [PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) also has something important to say:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**